# need help with grep on output of another grep command

Tags: grep, tail, cat

I have a file test.log. Very big log file. It has different levels of logging. For eg, `trace`, `debug`, `info`, `warning` and `error`.

Obviously `trace` level messages are just spamming at high speeds. I wanted to see all the messages without `trace` level logs.

So I did this:

```
cat test.log | grep -v "trace"
```

Works good.

Now I want to filter the remaining messages based on a certain keyword `keyword1`.

So I did this:

```
cat test.log | grep -v "trace" | grep "keyword1"
```

Works good.

Now I want to get that same output on a continual basis, I thought of replacing `cat` with `tail -f`.

```
tail -f test.log | grep -v "trace" | grep "keyword1"
```

But this does not work. I get no output at all.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I get my desired filtered 'tail & follow' output.

Thanks for the help.

*(btw, I am using cygwin... if that matters in any way)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encountering buffering issues: for performance reasons `grep` will keep quite a bit of output in its buffer and will output the whole chunk in one go. That means that when a line is read from the input, `grep` will send it to stdout once it has read (and let through) even more lines - which can be quite some time later when dealing with a log file that is being read-in using `tail -f`.

Many `grep` variants have a switch to turn-on line-buffered mode, which will output each line on its own - with some performance loss. For example [`GNU grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html) has a [`--line-buffered`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html#Other-Options) option to achieve this effect.

Just add that option (or the appropriate one for your version of `grep`) to all your `grep` invocations and you see some output as soon as a matching like is added to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, you're just encountering buffering delays.  So you will see a long period of nothing, followed by a short burst of lots of text, followed by another wait.  Read http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html for an explanation of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

`tail -f` follows the "new incoming lines" of a file. The periodic output will never reach the piped `grep` commands (at least not, until `tail` is terminated).

To periodically "follow" changes in those log files, you might want to use `watch` instead:

```
watch -n 1 -- 'tail -n 20 test.log | grep -v trace | grep keyword1'
```

This'll update every second (`-n 1`) the last 20 lines of the log file.

Comment: But as per your explanation `tail -n 20 test.log | grep -v trace` shouldn't work as well, but tail piped with 1 grep works. but 2 consecutive piped greps aren't working.

Comment: @bits The imperative change was from `tail -f` to `tail -n`. My example works well with one, let alone two hundred chained greps...